# rst.getTimestamp("upload_date") doesn't work in Amazon RDS MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, timestamp, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database table on AWS RDS which has a column named **upload_date** whose **TYPE** is **TIMESTAMP** and **DEFAULT** is **current_timestamp**.

I've done the same thing in my local MySQL db.

When I invoke the rst.getTimestamp("upload_date") in my local db connection, it works great.
However when I try the same thing on my AWS RDS MySQL,  I get this exception

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1033)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getTimestampFast(BufferRow.java:576)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6466)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6066)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6104)
    at org.udhc.gen.HealthRecord.getAllUploadedHealthRecords(HealthRecord.java:337)
    at org.udhc.gen.HealthRecord.main(HealthRecord.java:858)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was:

I had ALTERed the table to add this new column - so the previously entered rows had

00-00-00 00:00  ( or something similar )

That caused the above expection.

FIX:

```
UPDATE FORUM SET UPLOAD_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: You might want to consider fixing your code, so that it takes more appropriate action when a "zero date" value is returned.